# VUE - Archivo CSS importado en Componente modifica también otras vistas

Tags: css, vue.js

Tengo un archivo de estilos CSS `CarritoCompra.css`. Lo importo en el componente `TotalPedido.vue`.
Cómo es posible que èstilos de `CarritoCompra.css` estén modificando también la vista `Shop.vue` si sólo está importado en `TotalPedido.vue`?

Lo importo así: `import('../assets/styles/CarritoCompra.css')`

**TotalPedido.vue**

```
<template>

<div class="subtotal">
  <div class="datos">
    <label>Subtotal</label>
    <p>{{calcularSubtotal}} &euro;</p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="datos">
    <label>Envío</label> 
    <p>5 &euro;</p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
    <div class="datos">
      <label><span>Total</span></label>
      <p>{{calcularSubtotal + 5}} &euro;</p>
    </div>
    <p class="impuesto">Impuesto incluído</p>
    <button type="submit" class="boton"><router-link 
    to="/formularioCompra">Finalizar compra</router-link></button>
 </template>
 <script>
    import { mapState } from 'vuex'
    import('../assets/styles/CarritoCompra.css');
```

Comment: porque el css afecta a toda la pagina, salvo que este agregado en un componente con scoped....

Comment: @gbianchi he editado la pregunta con el código del componente. Como ves está importado el archivo CSS `import('../assets/styles/CarritoCompra.css')` y la etiqueta `<style scoped></style>`  la he eliminado ya que he imaginado que si estoy importando un archivo CSS, no es necesario que la use. De hecho he probado a incluirla con el `scoped` (por si acaso) y sigue igual.

Comment: porque el css debe ir en el componente... si no, deberias ver como se importa como scoped....

Comment: No sabía que había que indicar scoped al importar un archivo css. Gracias a tu pista lo arreglé así: `<style scoped src="../assets/styles/CarritoCompra.css"></style>`

Comment: ahhhh esa es buenisima.. ponelo como respuesta!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser que los archivos CSS importados, si se quiere que actúen únicamente en el archivo dónde se importan, hay que indicarlo también con scoped.
Lo arreglé con el siguiente código:

`<style scoped src="../assets/styles/CarritoCompra.css"></style>`